# Microsoft Authentication - Python Flask msal Example App Ported to FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, azure-ad-msal

I don't do much web work but I recently began using FastAPI and am building an MVC app with jinja2 templating that uses PowerBI embedded capacity to serve multiple embedded analytics in app owns data arrangement. All of this works beautifully. However, I'm wanting to add further modules and I'd like to use the msal package to do user authentication by routing a user to the Microsoft login page, letting them sign in against a multi-tenant app service I set up in Azure, and then redirecting back to my page via redirect URI, grabbing the token, and progressing with authorization. Microsoft saved a great example our [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp) for doing this in Flask. However, I am having fits porting the example to FastAPI.

I can get the user to the login screen and log in but I am having no luck capturing the token at my call back URI - it's appropriately routing but I am unable to capture the token from the response.

Has anyone (or can anyone) taken that super simple Flask example and ported it to FastAPI? Everything I find online for FAPI is back-end token-bearer headers for APIs - not meant for MVC apps.

Here's my current code. Messy because I have "tests" built in.

```
import msal
import requests
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates

from config import get_settings

settings = get_settings()
router = APIRouter()
templates = Jinja2Templates('templates')


# Works
@router.get('/login', include_in_schema=False)
async def login(request: Request):
    request.session['flow'] = _build_auth_code_flow(scopes=settings.AUTH_SCOPE)
    login_url = request.session['flow']['auth_uri']
    return templates.TemplateResponse('error.html', {'request': request, 'message': login_url})


# DOES NOT WORK - Pretty sure error is in here --------------------
@router.get('/getAToken', response_class=Response, include_in_schema=False)
async def authorize(request: Request):
    try:
        cache = _load_cache(request)
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
            request.session.get('flow'), request.session
        )
        if 'error' in result:
            return templates.TemplateResponse('error.html', {'request': request, 'message': result})
        request.session['user'] = result.get('id_token_claims')
        _save_cache(cache)
    except Exception as error:
        return templates.TemplateResponse('error.html', {'request': request, 'message': f'{error}: {str(request.query_params)}'})
    return templates.TemplateResponse('error.html', {'request': request, 'message': result})
# -----------------------------------------------------

    
def _load_cache(request: Request):
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if request.session.get("token_cache"):
        cache.deserialize(request.session["token_cache"])
    return cache


def _save_cache(request: Request, cache):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        request.session["token_cache"] = cache.serialize()


def _build_msal_app(cache=None, authority=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        settings.CLIENT_ID,
        authority=authority or settings.AUTH_AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
        token_cache=cache
    )


def _build_auth_code_flow(authority=None, scopes=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).initiate_auth_code_flow(
        scopes or [],
        redirect_uri=settings.AUTH_REDIRECT)


def _get_token_from_cache(scope=None):
    cache = _load_cache()  # This web app maintains one cache per session
    cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = cca.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])
        _save_cache(cache)
        return result
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Happy to answer any questions. Thank you.

Comment: For further clarity, I'm getting a "state mismatch" in the return response after seemingly successfully logging in. "state mismatch: dWASFCmYrjQzXnZv vs None: code=0.AXYA4G2......(about 200 more random characters)..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because FastAPI session variables are stored client-side as a cookie, which has a limit of 4096 bytes of data. The data being stored from the redirect url is pushes the cookie size over this limit and results in the data not being stored. [Starlette-session](https://github.com/auredentan/starlette-session) is an alternative SessionMiddleware that stores variables server-side, eliminating cookie limit. Below is a basic (but messy) implementation:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

from starlette_session import SessionMiddleware
from starlette_session.backends import BackendType

from redis import Redis

import uvicorn
import functools
import msal


app_client_id = "sample_msal_client_id"
app_client_secret = "sample_msal_client_secret"
tenant_id = "sample_msal_tenant_id"

app = FastAPI()


redis_client = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379)
app.add_middleware(
    SessionMiddleware,
    secret_key="SECURE_SECRET_KEY",
    cookie_name="auth_cookie",
    backend_type=BackendType.redis,
    backend_client=redis_client,
)

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

default_scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
token_cache_key = "token_cache"

# Private Functions - Start
def _load_cache(session):
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if session.get(token_cache_key):
        cache.deserialize(session[token_cache_key])
    return cache

def _save_cache(cache,session):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        session[token_cache_key] = cache.serialize()

def _build_msal_app(cache=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        app_client_id, 
        client_credential=app_client_secret,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
        token_cache=cache
    )

def _build_auth_code_flow(request):
    return _build_msal_app().initiate_auth_code_flow(
        default_scope, #Scopes
        redirect_uri=request.url_for("callback") #Redirect URI
    )

def _get_token_from_cache(session):
    cache = _load_cache(session)  # This web app maintains one cache per session
    cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = cca.acquire_token_silent(default_scope, account=accounts[0])
        _save_cache(cache,session)
        return result
# Private Functions - End


# Custom Decorators - Start
def authenticated_endpoint(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def is_authenticated(*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            request = kwargs["request"]
            token = _get_token_from_cache(request.session)
            if not token:
                return RedirectResponse(request.url_for("login"))
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        except:
            return RedirectResponse(request.url_for("login"))

    return is_authenticated
# Custom Decorators - End


# Endpoints - Start
@app.get("/")
@authenticated_endpoint
def index(request:Request):
    return {
        "result": "good"
    }

@app.get("/login")
def login(request:Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html",{
        "version": msal.__version__,
        'request': request,
        "config": {
            "B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY": False
        }
    })

@app.get("/oauth/redirect")
def get_redirect_url(request:Request):
    request.session["flow"] = _build_auth_code_flow(request)
    return RedirectResponse(request.session["flow"]["auth_uri"])

@app.get("/callback")
async def callback(request:Request):
    cache = _load_cache(request.session)
    result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(request.session.get("flow", {}), dict(request.query_params))
    if "error" in result:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("auth_error.html",{
            "result": result,
            'request': request
        })
    request.session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
    request.session[token_cache_key] = cache.serialize()
    return RedirectResponse(request.url_for("index"))
# Endpoints - End

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app",host='0.0.0.0', port=4557,reload=True)`
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you! A friend had helped me get to a similar answer using fastapi-cache. There are definitely a couple points from this answer that I'll further work in. Thank you for taking the time to include the example - EXTREMELY helpful.

Comment: @Richard can you provide your `fastapi-cache` based solution?